# PHP custom regroup array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to regroup array but I have problem on columns and grouping child arrays :
**My Array :**

```
[0] => Array
(
    [0] => 1393/03
    [1] => 5666562
    [2] => 5
)

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1393/03
        [1] => 491380
        [2] => 6
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1393/03
        [1] => 4210423
        [2] => 30
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1393/03
        [1] => 351000
        [2] => 55
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1393/03
        [1] => 53000
        [2] => 60
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1393/02
        [1] => 15799573
        [2] => 5
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1393/02
        [1] => 1144313
        [2] => 6
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1393/02
        [1] => 12131004
        [2] => 30
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1393/02
        [1] => 39000
        [2] => 55
    )
```

**Result:** (must be like this :)

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Date] => 1393/03
        [5] => 5666562
        [6] => 491380
        [30] => 4210423
        [60] => 53000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Date] => 1393/02
        [5] => 15799573
        [6] => 1144313
        [30] => 12131004
        [60] => 39000
    )
```

I try to do it my self with `foreach arrays` and references samples around internet and stack-overflow , but I don't find a good solution.

Comment: `foreach ($array as $values) $result[$values[0]][] = $values[1];` This gets you 90% of the way there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple foreach loop should suffice. Consider this example:

```
$new_values = array();
$values = array( array('1393/03', 5666562, 5), array('1393/03', 491380, 6), array('1393/03', 4210423, 30), array('1393/03', 351000, 55), array('1393/03', 53000, 60), array('1393/02', 15799573, 5), array('1393/02', 1144313, 6), array('1393/02', 12131004, 30), array('1393/02', 39000, 55),);

foreach($values as $key => $value) {
    $new_values[$value[0]]['Date'] = $value[0];
    $new_values[$value[0]][$value[2]] = $value[1];
}

$new_values = array_values($new_values);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_values);
echo "</pre>";
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/oZH0xQ)